# How to ensure ActiveStorage URL actually expires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

**EDIT**: Discussion is continued in the [Rails discussion group](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/how-to-ensure-activestorage-url-actually-expires/73932/2?u=sedubois).

For now this monkey-patch did the trick (apply it with `ActiveStorage::Blob.include(ActiveStorageBlobMonkeyPatch)`):

```
module ActiveStorageBlobMonkeyPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def signed_id
      ActiveStorage.verifier.generate(id, purpose: :blob_id, expires_in: 5.minutes)
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Original question**:

If I load a page containing a URL to an ActiveStorage attachment (*), wait over 5 minutes, copy the URL from the source code and paste it in a browser, it loads fine although I would expect it to fail as the expiry time has been exceeded. This seems to be because the base64-encoded part of the URL contains `"exp"=>nil`:

```rb
url = app.url_for(post.cover_image)
params = url[/blobs\/(.*)--/,1]
JSON.parse(Base64.decode64(params))
=> {"_rails"=>{"message"=>"BAhpJA==", "exp"=>nil, "pur"=>"blob_id"}}
```

Only after querying that URL does it perform a 302 redirect which leads to a new URL which itself does contains an expiry of 5 minutes in the future.

**How to protect images and other types of sensitive content (e.g. subscription-only) with ActiveStorage? How to ensure URLs for attachments and their variants will not be downloadable in the future?**

(*) Tested with a Rails 6.0.2.2 app with `Post`s configured with `has_one_attached :cover_image` and using ActiveStorage disk service. `config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in` was not defined and so defaults to 5 minutes. Posts were rendered with `style="background-image: url(#{url_for post.cover_image)})"` (not using variants for the sake of simplicity). The URL of the background image in the page source has the structure `/rails/active_storage/blobs/XXX--YYY/ZZZ.jpg` where XXX is the Base64-encoded part.